# Why my animation doesn't work for a compass made in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, compass, swiftui-animation

I am making a simple compass view with just basic things for a view and I would like to have it animated. I am using the compass of my physical device (iPhone 13 PRO).
So, everything seems to be fine - heading is correct, view is rotating but... the animation does not work, actually any of the animation types. However if I use it to rotate the whole ZStack is fine. It doesn't work once I am trying to rotate the gauge markers. Please see code below:

```
//
//  CompassView.swift
//  ExtasyCompleteNavigation
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 20.08.23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct CompassView: View {
    
    var heading: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                GeometryReader{ geometry in
                    
                    let width = geometry.size.width
                    let height = geometry.size.height
                    let fontSize = width/13
                    //compass background
                    Circle()
                    //compass heading display and direction
                    Text("\(-heading,specifier: "%.0f")°\n\(displayDirection())")
                        .font(Font.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: width/13))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .position(x: width/2, y:height/2)
                    //compass degree ring
                    Group{
                        MyShape(sections: 12, lineLengthPercentage: 0.15)
                            .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5))
                        MyShape(sections: 360, lineLengthPercentage: 0.15)
                            .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                        //compass arrow
                        Text("▼")
                            .font(Font.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: fontSize))
                            .position(x:width/2, y: height/200 )
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        PseudoBoat()
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 4)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .scaleEffect(x: 0.30, y: 0.55, anchor: .top)
                            .offset(y: geometry.size.height/5)
                    }

                    //heading values
                    ForEach(GaugeMarkerCompass.labelSet()) { marker in
                        CompassLabelView(marker: marker,  geometry: geometry)
                            .position(CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2))
                        
                    }
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: heading))
                    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3), value: heading)

                }.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)

            }
        }
    }
    
    //function can be moved in a structure with the rest of the tools in swift file
    func displayDirection() -> String {
        switch heading {
        case 0:
            return "N"
        case 90:
            return "E"
        case 180:
            return "S"
        case 270:
            return "W"
        case 90..<180:
            return "SE"
        case 180..<270:
            return "SW"
        case 270..<360:
            return "NW"
        default:
            return "NE"
        }
        
    }
    
    //to be moved to a swift file and keep it separate
    public struct CompassLabelView: View {
        let marker: GaugeMarker
        let geometry: GeometryProxy
        
        @State var fontSize: CGFloat = 12
        @State var paddingValue: CGFloat = 100
        
        public var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(marker.label)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .font(Font.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: geometry.size.width * 0.05))
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 0))
                    .padding(.bottom, geometry.size.width * 0.72)
            }.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: marker.degrees))
                .onAppear {
                    paddingValue = geometry.size.width * 0.72
                    fontSize = geometry.size.width * 0.07
                }
        }
    }
    struct GaugeMarkerCompass: Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id = UUID()
        
        let degrees: Double
        let label: String
        
        init(degrees: Double, label: String) {
            self.degrees = degrees
            self.label = label
        }
        
        // adjust according to your needs
        static func labelSet() -> [GaugeMarker] {
            return [
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 0, label: "N"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 30, label: "30"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 60, label: "60"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 90, label: "E"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 120, label: "120"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 150, label: "150"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 180, label: "S"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 210, label: "210"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 240, label: "240"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 270, label: "W"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 300, label: "300"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 330, label: "330")
            ]
        }
    }
}

struct CompassView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CompassView(heading: 0)
            .background(.white)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]. Without it, no one can build your code

Comment: The only animation modifier is based on the value ```heading```, but this is neither a state variable nor a binding, so it will not change during the lifetime of the view. Try making it a binding to the state variable that is presumably owned elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, where you `attach` the rotation and the animation to the `VStack`,
as shown in the example code, or if you prefer,
you can `attach` the rotationEffect and animation to the
`CompassView` itself in `ContentView`.

Also rename `GaugeMarkerCompass` to `GaugeMarker`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var heading: CGFloat = 0.0  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 44) {
            // for testing
            Button("change heading") {
                heading += 10.0
            }.padding(10).buttonStyle(.bordered)
            
            CompassView(heading: heading)  // <-- here
//                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: heading))  // <--- here
//                .animation(.linear(duration: 2), value: heading)  // <--- here
        }
    }
}

struct CompassView: View {
    let heading: CGFloat  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                GeometryReader{ geometry in
                    let width = geometry.size.width
                    let height = geometry.size.height
                    let fontSize = width/13
                    //compass background
                    Circle()
                    //compass heading display and direction
                    Text("\(-heading,specifier: "%.0f")°\n\(displayDirection())")
                        .font(Font.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: width/13))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .position(x: width/2, y:height/2)
                    //compass degree ring
                    Group{
                        MyShape(sections: 12, lineLengthPercentage: 0.15)
                            .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5))
                        MyShape(sections: 360, lineLengthPercentage: 0.15)
                            .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                        //compass arrow
                        Text("▼")
                            .font(Font.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: fontSize))
                            .position(x:width/2, y: height/200 )
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
//                        PseudoBoat()
//                            .stroke(lineWidth: 4)
//                            .foregroundColor(.white)
//                            .scaleEffect(x: 0.30, y: 0.55, anchor: .top)
//                            .offset(y: geometry.size.height/5)
                    }
                    //heading values
                    ForEach(GaugeMarker.labelSet()) { marker in   // <-- here
                        CompassLabelView(marker: marker,  geometry: geometry)
                            .position(CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2))
                    }
                    // <--- NOT here
                }.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            }
            // --- here to stop the fading of labels
            .transaction { transaction in
                transaction.animation = nil
            }
        }
        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: heading))  // <--- here
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2), value: heading)  // <--- here
    }
    
    //function can be moved in a structure with the rest of the tools in swift file
    func displayDirection() -> String {
        switch heading {
        case 0:
            return "N"
        case 90:
            return "E"
        case 180:
            return "S"
        case 270:
            return "W"
        case 90..<180:
            return "SE"
        case 180..<270:
            return "SW"
        case 270..<360:
            return "NW"
        default:
            return "NE"
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after I played around a little bit with the answer from @workingdog I have made the following changes and I would like to post them in case anybody needs that help.

I decided to split the fixed and the moving parts of my compass.
here is the code and a picture of the fixed part:
[fixed_compass_part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJP4y.png)

here is the code

```
//
//  CompassStaticView.swift
//  ExtasyCompleteNavigation
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 22.08.23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct CompassStaticView: View {
    
    var heading: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                
                let width = geometry.size.width
                //let width: CGFloat = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
                let height = geometry.size.height


                let fontSize = width/15
                
                Circle()
                    .position(.init(x: width/2, y: height/2))
                Circle()
                    .position(.init(x: width/2, y: height/2))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.02, y:0.02, anchor: .center)
                Text("▼")
                    .font(Font.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: fontSize))
                    .position(x:width/2, y: height/2 )
                    .offset(y: -width/2.05)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text("\(heading, specifier: "%.0f")°\(displayDirection())")
                    .font(Font.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: fontSize ))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .position(x: width/2, y:height/1.39)
                PseudoBoat()
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 4)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.28, y: 0.58, anchor: .top)
                    .offset(y: geometry.size.height/5.5)
                
            }//.overlay(CompassView(heading: 0))
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            
        }
    }
    
    //function can be moved in a structure with the rest of the tools in swift file
    func displayDirection() -> String {
        switch heading {
            
        case 22.5..<67.5:
            return "NE"
        case 67.5..<112.5:
            return "E"
        case 112.5..<157.5:
            return "SE"
        case 157.5..<202.5:
            return "S"
        case 202.5..<247.5:
            return "SW"
        case 247.5..<292.5:
            return "W"
        case 292.5..<337.5:
            return "NW"
        default:
            return "N"
        }
        
    }
}

struct CompassStaticView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CompassStaticView(heading: 0)
    }
}
```

Then I made the rotation and the animation suggested in the answer which I accepted and I applied the transaction which prevents the labels from fading away (very useful by the way) and added .rotationEffect and .animation to the VStack.

see picture: [compass_moving_part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck0AS.png)
here is the code:

```
//
//  CompassView.swift
//  ExtasyCompleteNavigation
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 20.08.23.
//

import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct CompassView: View {
    
    var heading: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                GeometryReader{ geometry in
                    
                    //compass degree ring
                    
                    Group{
                        MyCompassShape(sections: 12, lineLengthPercentage: 0.15)
                            .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5))
                        
                        MyCompassShape(sections: 360, lineLengthPercentage: 0.15)
                            .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                    }
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.75, y:0.75)
                    
                    //heading values
                    ForEach(GaugeMarkerCompass.labelSet()) { marker in
                        CompassLabelView(marker: marker,  geometry: geometry)
                            .position(CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2))
                        
                    }
                }
            }.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        }.transaction { transaction in
            transaction.animation = nil
        }
        //rotate only the second Vstack
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -heading))  // why it has to be minus? is it a bug?
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: heading)// <--- here

    }
    
    
    struct MyCompassShape : Shape {
        var sections : Int
        var lineLengthPercentage: CGFloat
        
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let radius = rect.width / 1.6
            let degreeSeparation : Double = 360.0 / Double(sections)
            var path = Path()
            for index in 0..<Int(360.0/degreeSeparation) {
                let degrees = Double(index) * degreeSeparation
                let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
                let innerX = center.x + (radius - rect.size.width * lineLengthPercentage / 2) * CGFloat(cos(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let innerY = center.y + (radius - rect.size.width * lineLengthPercentage / 2) * CGFloat(sin(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let outerX = center.x + radius * CGFloat(cos(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let outerY = center.y + radius * CGFloat(sin(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: innerX, y: innerY))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: outerX, y: outerY))
            }
            return path
        }
    }
    //to be moved to a swift file and keep it separate
    public struct CompassLabelView: View {
        let marker: GaugeMarker
        let geometry: GeometryProxy
        
        @State var fontSize: CGFloat = 12
        @State var paddingValue: CGFloat = 100
        
        public var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text(marker.label)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .font(Font.custom("AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: geometry.size.width * 0.05))
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 0))
                    .padding(.bottom, geometry.size.width * 0.7)
            }.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: marker.degrees))
                .onAppear {
                    paddingValue = geometry.size.width * 0.72
                    fontSize = geometry.size.width * 0.07
                    
                }
        }
    }
    
    struct GaugeMarkerCompass: Identifiable, Hashable {
        let id = UUID()
        
        let degrees: Double
        let label: String
        
        init(degrees: Double, label: String) {
            self.degrees = degrees
            self.label = label
        }
        
        // adjust according to your needs
        static func labelSet() -> [GaugeMarker] {
            return [
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 0, label: "N"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 30, label: "30"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 60, label: "60"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 90, label: "90"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 120, label: "120"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 150, label: "150"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 180, label: "S"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 210, label: "210"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 240, label: "240"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 270, label: "W"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 300, label: "300"),
                GaugeMarker(degrees: 330, label: "330")
                
            ]
        }
    }
}

struct CompassView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CompassView(heading: 0)
            .background(.black)
    }
}
```

At the end in the ContentView, I just overlay them and everything seems to work as expected:
[compass_complete_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsZVa.png)
see code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  ExtasyCompleteNavigation
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 13.06.23.
//

import SwiftUI
import CocoaMQTT

struct ContentView: View {
    
    //instance of the ConnectionManager which is observableobject
    @StateObject var mqttManager = MQTTManager()
    @StateObject var compassHeading = CompassHeading()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            CompassStaticView(heading: compassHeading.degrees)
                .overlay(CompassView(heading: compassHeading.degrees))

            
            AnemometerView(windAngle: mqttManager.windAngle, windSpeed: mqttManager.windSpeed)
            
            
        }.onAppear{
            
            //that is commented so it doesn't connect every time to the RPi server
            //if you want to test, you have uncomment that
            _ = mqttManager.mqttClient.connect()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.white)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I am using the internal compass of the iPhone for the moment and the heading is taken from there. It is located in a separate file called CompassLogic

code:

```
//
//  CompassLogic.swift
//  ExtasyCompleteNavigation
//
//  Created by Vasil Borisov on 21.08.23.
//

import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreLocation

class CompassHeading: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    @Published var degrees: Double = .zero {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    
    override init() {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        }
    }
    
    
    //fix the logic here when passing through 0
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        self.degrees = newHeading.magneticHeading
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34883754)

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that, I just edited the answer to get rid of the additional question.